# Can we have Live Agent enabled in custom app(not console type of app)

Tags: app, servicecloud, liveagent

Is there a way where we can enable Live Agent in non-console type of app(in custom app).
'Live Agent User' feature licenses are available.

Comment: No. Currently you can use it in Console only.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from Spring ‘13, the Live Agent console isn’t available for new Live Agent customers. If you were a live agent customer prior to Spring 13 you should have access to the Live Agent console which would allow you to include this tab or a link to the tab in a custom app.